# Replace <a> </a> with href in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
content='<p>Hello, the web site is <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></p>. <p>The search engine is <a href="https://www.baidu.com">Baidu</a></p>.'
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
```

Now I want to replace the whole `<a> </a>` with the url address in href. So I want to get the expected result:

```
Hello, the web site is https://www.google.com. The search engine is https://www.baidu.com.
```

Anyone can provide a solution?

Comment: and what is the problem ? first use BS to find `<a>`  and get `href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find `a` and get `href` then you can add `href` to previous sibling and remove `a`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content='<p>Hello, the web site is <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></p>. <p>The search engine is <a href="https://www.baidu.com">Baidu</a></p>.'
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

# find all `a`
all_a = soup.findAll('a')

for a in all_a:
    # find `href` in `a`
    href = a['href']

    #print('--- before ---')
    #print(soup)

    # add `href` to `previousSibling`
    a.previousSibling.replaceWith(a.previousSibling + href)

    # remove `a`
    a.extract()

    #print('--- after ---')
    #print(soup)

print(soup)

'<p>Hello, the web site is https://www.google.com</p>. <p>The search engine is https://www.baidu.com</p>.'
```